# JavaScript removeEventListener by variable name

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to remove an even listener based on variable instead of event?  I want to remove the two eventListeners I set but don't want to remove others a 3rd party website may have enabled.

```
var scrollVar = window.addEventListener('scroll', someFunction, false);
window.removeEventListener(scrollVar);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeEventListener` takes a second parameter, the specific callback Function you want to remove.  So in your case you can do what you want by passing `someFunction` in to the call, it will not remove other handlers.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', someFunction, false);
window.removeEventListener('scroll', someFunction, false);
```